# Plot Real Time Serial Data using Python - with Arduino

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to build a code to make communications between my code and my Arduino Uno. I have a temperature sensor (tmp36) connected to the Arduino board, in the COM3, and I want to plot the temperature values in real time. I also have a start button, to start getting data and plot it in the graph, and a stop button to stop doing that.
When I run my code, I get a message saying: "could not convert string to float: b'Anal'", refering to line 19: " data = np.append(data,float(a[0:4]))". Can you tell me what is wrong? And would you be able to stop any more errors?
Thank You for your time!

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import serial as sr

root = Tk()
root.title("Communications")
root.geometry('1920x1080')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(background='black')

data = np.array([])
cond = False

def plot_data():
    global cond, data
    if (cond == True):
        a = s.readline()
        a.decode()
        if(len(data) < 100):
            data = np.append(data,float(a[0:4]))
        else:
            data[0:99] = data[1:100]
            data[99] = float(a[0:4])
        lines.set_xdata(np.arange(0, len(data)))
        lines.set_ydata(data)
        graph_1.draw()
    root.after(1, plot_data)

def plot_start():
    global cond
    cond = True
    s.reset_input_buffer()

def plot_stop():
    global cond
    cond = False

#graph
fig1 = Figure(facecolor="#090b80", figsize=(16,9), dpi=75)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title('Temperature', color='white', fontsize=14, fontweight="bold")
ax1.set_xlabel('Time, s', color='white', fontsize=10, fontweight="bold")
ax1.set_ylabel('ºC', color='white', fontsize=10, fontweight="bold")
ax1.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 50)
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color('#ffffff')
ax1.spines['top'].set_color('#090b80')
ax1.spines['right'].set_color('#090b80')
ax1.spines['left'].set_color('#ffffff')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#ffffff')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#ffffff')
lines = ax1.plot([], [], color='white')[0]
ax1.set_facecolor("#090b80")

graph_1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=root)
graph_1.get_tk_widget().place(x=10, y=10, width=540, height=344)
graph_1.draw()

control_frame = Frame(root, bg="#242729", width=893, height=501)
control_frame.place(x=663, y=467)

root.update()
button_1 = Button(control_frame, text="Start", bg="#1cba26", fg="white", font=('arial', 20,'bold'), padx=101, activebackground="#109419", activeforeground="white", borderwidth=0, relief=RAISED, cursor="hand2", command=lambda:plot_start())
button_1.place(x=10, y=107.5)

root.update()
button_2 = Button(control_frame, text="Stop", bg="#eb0c0c", fg="white", font=('arial', 20,'bold'), padx=101.4, activebackground="#990909", activeforeground="white", borderwidth=0, relief=RAISED, cursor="hand2", command=lambda:plot_stop())
button_2.place(x=304, y=107.5)

#start serial port
s = sr.Serial('COM3', 9600)
s.reset_input_buffer()

root.after(1, plot_data)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of this, but the Arduino IDE has a built in serial plotter:
https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-serial-plotter

Comment: I know but I want to receive a bunch of other information. And I want to put my own style to the plotters.

Answer (score 0):

I think so set a timeout: `s = sr.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)`, but the main problem is this: `a=a.decode()`, you don't use `a=`. And if decode ypu the data, are this string type, but you use list. This problem can you solution:

```
import ast

i = b'0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,999' # i is a bytes type val
dec=i.decode() #decode this
print(type(dec))

ldat=ast.literal_eval(dec) #convert str to list

print (ldat[3])
print (ldat[9])#here can use more characters data
```

And you can help the responders, if write an example line of readed data, arduino example and the full error message.

Good luck!

Sorry my english isn't perfect.